# How can I make the animation of a button happen when pressed on the mobile screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm sorry if my English is bad at first.

[The button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmVd6.png)
This is the button I want to run the animation when pressed.

[Animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caSen.png)

[Sprites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8TBi.png) I want to change between these two states when pressing the button

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Animations;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{

 private Animator animator;

 public void SetTrigger(string Pressed) { }

 Collider2D col;

 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     animator.SetFloat("Position", 0);

     if (Input.touchCount > 0)
     {
         Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
         Vector2 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
   
         if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
         {
             Collider2D touchedCollider = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPosition);
             if (col == touchedCollider)
             {
                 animator.SetFloat("Position", 1);
             }
         }
     }
  }
```

}

This is how the code has been after the last attempt I have made, it has things that may not make sense because I have been mixing things while testing. I have tried it with floats, bools and triggers. With the bool it has worked halfway for me, if I touched the button it did not sink but if from unity I pressed the button manually changing the boolean to true, and after touching from the mobile screen it recognized the touch and returned the button to the original position. In all situations what did not work well was the touch control but I have revised the touch control code and I would say that it is fine.

Sorry if it is not understood well, I am new to unity and programming, also English is not my main language

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Button does not already have implementation for what you are trying to achieve? Check what options are available under "Transition" in Button inspector. You can pick between Color Tint, Sprite Swap or Animation there, I suppose it handles most of the cases and I've never seen anyone implemeting animations to button in custom way.

Comment: Thanks, now I am closer to what I want, but the only thing that fails me is that the button does not work when I touch it with the mouse in unity or from the mobile. This had already happened to me with something else that I tried to do and I did not know how to solve it. Do I have to add a canvas or an eventsystem? The button has activated the one that is interactable and the object has a collider with trigger that I do not know if it is necessary

Comment: You need to have EventSystem component somewhere, I suppose you need InputModule too, I'm not sure just check out EventsSystem on default scene in new project, there should be one, or at least get added automaticaly when you start creating UI (just create Image or the button so the UI structure appears). The other option is that button does not have raycastTarget = true on its Image component, or it is in CanvasGroup overriding it to raycastTarget = false, it may also be overlapped by other Image with raycastTarget = true that consumes input event. There are many possible reasons for that.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have made it. I think the problem was that i need a EventSystem and you have to use a image instead of a sprite renderer what i was using.